# In place off network upgrade to server 2019

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Ok, I made a backup image of an AD and have it hosted in Hyper-V machine with no network on a separate pc. Unfortunately, it will not boot normally so the only way I am able to boot it and login is by booting through directory service repair mode. From there I have the server 2019 iso mounted as a disk. I can not run it to do an in place upgrade because I get the message saying I can't install windows while running in safe mode.
I have tried the following cmd commands to start the installer service and have had no success.

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal\MSIServer" /VE /T REG_SZ /F /D "Service"

net start msiserver
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It’s impossible to upgrade Windows while in Safe Mode (or Directory Service Repair Mode).

Comment: Yes, you need to have a working install in order to begin an in place install/upgrade of Windows. You cannot do it from safe mode.

Comment: Understood... I'll have to scrap this project and figure something else out then. Thank you.